# Different Version Problems in Restoring Sharepoint Sİte

Tags: powershell, migration, backup

I'm trying to move a Sharepoint site from one Sharepoint 2010 server to another.

I used the [Backup-SPSite cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx) to create a backup file.

It gives the error below after I try to restore with the [Restore-SPSite cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655.aspx):

> Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version '1178817357.0.6541431.0' or later.

When I use `get-spfarm | select BuildVersion` to get the build version, I get 14.0.4762.1000 at both source and destination.

Any ideas?

Comment: Closing this, as problem was apparently caused by a mistake in using the PS cmdlets per @frbry's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the cause to the problem. I was using Backup-SPSite to export my data and Import-SPWeb to import it. Obviously, you should Export-SPWeb instead of Backup-SPSite, if you want to use Import-SPWeb method.

Comment: I think this is not a problem but a mistake, you mentioned you did Backup\Restore -SPSite.

Comment: You're right, this was a mistake.

Comment: @frbry In view of that, the original question is really moot. We should therefore close or possibly delete this question. Does anyone object?

Comment: @SPDoctor I agree but I think it's better not to delete the question as it may help someone else in future, by reminding to check this kind of mistake.

Comment: @frbry Yes, I know what you mean.

Comment: Easy mistake imo. Keep the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check the patch level of the farm you are trying to restore the site collection backup into, versus the original farm. Could the source farms have had a Cumulative Update or hotfix applied? The error message suggests that the destination farm is at an older patch level - the farm you are restoring to must be at the same or more recent patch level. Don't forget that after patching you need to run the SharePoint Configuration wizard to get the patches applied and the database schemas updated.

I also read somewhere that a weird build number can be reported if you try to restore a file that is not actually a backup file (e.g. an export file, or a corrupt backup file). It might be worth having another try, if you have not already done so.

More information about checking versions [here](http://www.sharepointdesignerstepbystep.com/Blog/Articles/How%20To%20find%20the%20SharePoint%20version.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is about the Sharepoint Foundation build number, not the Sharepoint Farm. If rolling out the update is not an option, or you just want to bypass the Build version validation, you can use the "stsadm" command. Find the step by step instructions on this post: http://hints-on-it.blogspot.com/2011/11/your-backup-is-from-different-version.html

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Are build numbers changed when updates are applied? From what I understand, at least on our MOSS systems, patching updates settings in the database but aren't directly related to build version.